# dynamic mat-checkbox not displaying from FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want the mat-checkboxes to be populated from an array. I am able to build the form group and form array and see their contents in the console. But I am unable to get the list of devices to display using ngFor. I've looked up multiple examples of reactive forms, and think I'm doing this html correctly, but obviously I'm missing something.

Here is the ts code:

```
import { Aircraft } from '../../shared/aircraft';
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormArray, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material";
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';

interface IAircraftCheckbox {
  imei: string;
  selected: boolean;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-historical-track-dialog',
  templateUrl: './historical-track-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./historical-track-dialog.component.scss',],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})


export class HistoricalTrackDialogComponent implements OnInit {
aircraftData: any[];
imeiToTrack: string[];
breakpoint: number;
form: FormGroup;
aircraftArray: FormArray;
allSelected: boolean;

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<HistoricalTrackDialogComponent>,
              private fb: FormBuilder,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: Aircraft[]) {
    this.aircraftData = data;
    console.log('historical track dialog, this.aircraftList: ', data);
    this.aircraftArray = new FormArray([new FormControl('CAP')]);
    this.aircraftArray = this.mapAircraftToCheckboxArrayGroup( this.aircraftData);
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      aircraftList: this.aircraftArray
    });
    this.allSelected = false;
    console.log('this.form: ', this.form);
    console.log('this.aircraftList = ', this.form.controls.aircraftList);
  }

  mapAircraftToCheckboxArrayGroup( aircraft: Aircraft[]): FormArray {
    return this.fb.array(aircraft.map((i) => {
      return this.fb.group ({
        imei: i.IMEI,
        selected: false,
        name: i.DeviceName
      });
    }));
  }

  checkboxToggle(e) {
    console.log('CheckboxToggle, e=', e);
    console.log('source.id', e.source.id);
    console.log('status: ', e.checked);
  }

  toggleAll(e) {
    for (const control of this.aircraftArray.controls) {
      if (this.allSelected === true ) {
        console.log('setting ', control.value.name, 'to false');
        control.value.selected = false;
      } else {
        control.value.selected = true;
        console.log('setting ', control.value.name, 'to true');
      }
    }
    this.allSelected = this.allSelected === true ? false : true;
    this.form.markAsDirty();

  }
  ngOnInit() {
this.breakpoint = (window.innerWidth <= 690) ? 1 : 4;
  }
  onResize(event) {
    this.breakpoint = (event.target.innerWidth <= 690) ? 1 : 4;
  }

  close() {
    console.log('close, formArray: ', this.aircraftArray.controls);
    for (const control of this.aircraftArray.controls) {
      if (control.value.selected === true ) {
        console.log('aircraft checked: ', control.value.name);
      }
    }
    this.dialogRef.close();

  }
```

}

and here is the html:

```
<div class="aList-container"
      fxLayout="column"
      fxLayoutGap="10px"
      fxLayoutAlign="start"
       style="width:500px;max-height:50%">

      <div >
          <div class="a-list-title" >
            <h3>AIRCRAFT LIST</h3>
            <hr>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="checkboxList" [formGroup]="form">

        <mat-grid-list [cols]="breakpoint" rowHeight="30px" gutterSize="0px" formArrayName="aircraftList" (window:resize)="onResize($event)">
            <mat-grid-tile fxLayout="column"  *ngFor="let aircraftName of aircraftList.value" [formGroup]="aircraftList">
              <mat-checkbox [formControl]="aircraftName.get('selected')">
                <!--{{aircraftName.get('name').value}}-->
                {{aircraftList}}
              </mat-checkbox>

              </mat-grid-tile>
              <mat-grid-tile fxLayout="column" >
                  <mat-checkbox id="toggle-all" ng-model="all" (click)="toggleAll($event)">Toggle All</mat-checkbox>
              </mat-grid-tile>
        </mat-grid-list>
        <div class="close-button">
            <button class="mat-raised-button " routerLink="/home" (click)="close()" style="margin: 10px;position:center">Close</button>
        </div>

      </div>
</div>
```

At runtime, I get an error from the template telling me that controls or value is not defined (tried both). But they are there when I log the formArray:
   [image]

[image]

All I see is a blank dialog. 
[image]

I'm sure I'm missing something simple and fundamental to reactive forms but have been chasing my tail for 3 days now.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <mat-grid-tile fxLayout="column"  *ngFor="let aircraftName of aircraftList.value" [formGroup]="aircraftList">
> ```

You haven't defined any `aircraftList` object. It is a control inside a form group:

> ```
> this.form = new FormGroup({
>   aircraftList: this.aircraftArray
> });
> ```

So you should access it that way as well:

```
 <mat-grid-tile fxLayout="column"  *ngFor="let aircraftName of form.controls.aircraftList.value" [formGroup]="aircraftList">
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an even more bizarre error: ERROR TypeError: _v.context.$implicit.get is not a function. Still not getting any checkboxes. Also tells me that form.controls.aircraftList is not defined even though I can see it in the console

Comment: There appear to be a lot of other design problems with your code. `form.controls.aircraftList.value` should probably be `form.controls.aircraftList.controls` but that change might require other things to change. Also, you are defining `aircraftArray` twice. Might only be scratching the surface. If you can create a StackBlitz example, it will be a lot easier to debug than static code, plus you will probably sort out some of your own problems in the process.

Comment: Redesigned entire component from scratch, spent another full day researching reactive forms and now everything works as it should. Reactive forms are not trivial when you want to get into not so simple dynamic type forms.